# message.mentions returns undefined when message is not undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js

I appreciate you looking into my problem and trying to fix it!

**The problem**
The problem is that whenever I try to use `message.mentions` inside of my code, it always returns as undefined.

**What have I tried?**
I have tried going into the discord.js server and asking people there to help me and they didn't help me at all.

It would be great if someone could help!

The code where the issue occurs is:

```js
interaction.channel.awaitMessages({ messagefilter, max: 1, time: 20000, errors: ['time'] }).then(async message => {
    console.log(message.mentions) // logs undefined
    if (message.mentions) { // if statement fails
        // this part doesn't run
    } else {
        // this part does run
    }
}).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [TextChannel#awaitMessages()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) method returns a **`Collection` of messages, not a single Message object.** Simply defining it as `message` does not make a `Collection` a singular `Message` object, you have to get the `first()` property of the collection and check the mentions in that! Like so:

```js
interaction.channel.awaitMessages({ messagefilter, max: 1, time: 20000, errors: ['time'] }).then(async message => { 
console.log(message.first().mentions);
...
})
```

You're trying to log `Collection#mentions` in your console right now which won't be present.